# Java 2D collision response method

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection, collision

Recently I have been playing around with basic 2D java game programming and have been having a lot of fun discovering things on my own, but I have come up with a problem. I have created a simple collision method that has been extremely buggy. So my question is how to change the x and y of the player when they collid with a block. I have tried the below code and it is recognizing when the player has collided but it doesn't set his x and y to the x and y to the tempx and y. Code:

```
private void update(){
    tempx = player.getX(); 
    tempy = player.getY();
    collided = checkCollision();
    if(collided == false){
        player.update();
    }
    else if(collided){
        player.setX((int)tempx);
        player.setY((int)tempy);
        System.out.println("COLLIDED");
    }
}

private boolean checkCollision(){
    for(int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++){
        Tile t = tiles.get(i);
        Rectangle tr = t.getBounds();
        if(tr.intersects(player.getBounds())){
            return tr.intersects(getBounds());
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The collision is being detected but the player x and y aren't being changed accordingly. If you need more code or have any questions just ask. Thanks for any help:)

P.S. I have tried adding gravity and the collision only works for the top of the blocks if that is any help

Below is the player.update() method:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int k = e.getKeyCode();
    if(k != 0){
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            y -= vy;
        }
        else if(k == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            x -= vx;
        }
        else if(k == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            y += vy;
        }
        else if(k == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            x += vx;
        }
    }
}
public void update(){

}
```

Comment: Isn't tempx and tempy the players original x and y coordinates?  So when the calls player.setX((int)tempx) and player.setY((int)tempy) are made, aren't just setting the original coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your update method.

```
private void update(){
    tempx = player.getX(); // tempx now is the same as the players x location
    tempy = player.getY();
    collided = checkCollision();
    if(collided == false){
        player.update();
    }
    else if(collided){
        player.setX((int)tempx);  // you set players location equal to temp, which is 
        player.setY((int)tempy);  // already the players location
        System.out.println("COLLIDED");
    }
}
```

Since you are setting the players location equal to the location that it is currently in, you're not going to see the character move anywhere at all. You'll probably want to change the values of `tempx` and `tempy`

```
tempx = player.getX() + 10; 
tempy = player.getY() + 10;
```

**Update**

There seems to be some confusion about how the updating process is working.

Consider the following:

- character starts at (0,0)
- some object at (2,2) chich would cause a collision

Given the above the following happens in your update method and IN THIS ORDER

- `tempx = player.getX()` both x's are now 0
- `tempy = player.getY()` both y's are now 0
- checks collision, there are none
- since no collisions, player is updated. (I'll presume the update method moves the character (+1,+1). So character is now at location (1,1).
- tempx and tempy are set to getX and getY again. X and Y are now both 1. Now tempx and tempy are also 1
- no collisions, so character is updated (moved) to (2,2)
- tempx and tempy are set to getX and getY. X and Y are now both 2, so tempx and tempy are also 2.
- checks collisions, its true there was one at (2,2)
- because there was a collision you then "move" the character to tempx and tempy, BUT tempx and tempy are the same value as character.getX and character.getY.

You have to set `tempx` and `tempy` equal to the characters location outside of the update loop if you want them to remain the same throughout the characters updated movements.

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted to happen. It sets the tempx or what the x originally was so that if it doesn't collide it can change the players position. But if it does collide then it resets the players position to what it was before the update

Comment: @user2280906 But the `update()` method is likely called hundreds of times per second. Every time the `update()` method is called it takes the new, current position of the player and sets that equal to tempx. At any given point tempx is going to be the same as `player.getX();`

Comment: @user2280906 so if there is NO collision, it updates the location of the player. The next time around it RESETS the values of tempx and tempy to the NEW position of player and then checks again to see if there is a collision. If there is this time, then it sets the current value of player to tempx and tempy, which are still the current value of `player.getX()` and `player.getY();`

Comment: You were right up until the end. If there is collision it resets the player position to what it was before he moved. Where he actually moves is in the player.update();

Comment: So basically what my question is is how do I only move the player when the update is called. The code for the keylistener and the player.update(); is above.

Comment: The tempx and tempy are what the player was before he moved so that if there was a collision it can set the x and y to what the player was before the move. And by the way, thanks for all of the help and for taking your time to help try and solve this problem with me.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I took what you said into consideration, did some extra research and I think I know the way I want to tackle this.